# Send console logs to an user in pm discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

Hello is it possible to send the console logs in pm to an user (me).

Example i have
console.log('User generated a key')
And i would like that it sends it to me each time there is a new log in console.

Comment: Use `User.send()` and supply what you log

Answer (score 1):

```js
let user = client.users.cache.get('') //your id
user.send()// what u logged, put that in a var and send it
```

Comment: thanks i hope this works !